# How to add a git remote using ssh where the location of the remote repository is under the root folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to add a remote to my repository abc. It's a remote Windows server that I acces using the account user. The default directory that I enter when I ssh into user is `C:/Users/user` but the remote repository is located in `C:/Git/Repository.git`.

I tried adding the remote like this:
`git remote add new-origin user@server.sample.net/c/Git/Repository.git`
`git remote add new-origin user@server.sample.net/C:/Git/Repository.git`
`git remote add new-origin user@server.sample.net:22/C:/Git/Repository.git`
but none of these work, they all give the same error:

```
fatal: ''/c/Git/Repository.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The remote server is running Windows 10 Professional and OpenSSH for Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `Repository` exists on your remote server ?

Comment: Yes, I created the directory `C:/Git/Repository.git`, opened git bash there and entered the command `git init --bare`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a folder named with the extension `git` as in `Repository.git` ?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII the Repository.git folder has the subfolders "hooks, objects, refs and info" and the files "config, HEAD and description"

Comment: Did you manually create/rename this folder? Those objects should be in a folder simply called `.git` which should be inside your project root folder named whatever, such as `Repository`. In that case, then I would expect your needed command to be `git remote add new-origin user@server.sample.net/c:/Git/Repository` but I don't use Windows so really not sure.